# Yii2: How to use conditions inside GridView Widget

Tags: gridview, model, yii2, action

I have a Gridview Widget in my project with `'filterModel' => $searchModel,` that shows the user a filter fields and the action column for loading action buttons. My problem is, I want to reuse this Gridview with two separate actions of the controller. One action i.e. the `index` action loads the data for the user and allows the user to filter using the filter fields and do various actions in the action column. The other `controller action` is for reports. This produces a pdf report and I don't want the filter fields and the action column to be there in the reports. 
Is there a way of passing a condition to the Gridview without having to rewrite the whole code using the `if else` because I find this ineffective in terms of amount of code used. Here is the code I have written so far but need a shorter form with minimal code.

index.php

```
<?php 

$action_id = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;

if ($action_id == 'index') {
    \yiister\adminlte\widgets\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        "condensed" => false,
        "hover" => true,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'name',
            'mobile_number',
            'sex',
            [ 
                // the attribute 
                'attribute' => 'date', 
                // format the value 
                'value' => function ($model) { 
                    if (extension_loaded('intl')) { 
                        return Yii::t('app', '{0, date, MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm}', [$model->date]); 
                    } else { 
                        return date($model->date); 
                    } 
                }, 
                // some styling? 
                'headerOptions' => [ 
                    'class' => 'col-md-2' 
                ], 
                // here we render the widget 
                'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([ 
                    'model' => $searchModel, 
                    'attribute' => 'date_range',
                    'pluginOptions' => [ 
                        'format' => 'd-m-Y', 
                        'autoUpdateInput' => false 
                    ] 
                ]) 
            ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'officer',
            'value' => 'officer.first_name'
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
             'template' => '{view}&nbsp{update}',   //{view}&nbsp;
             'buttons' => [
                 'view' => function($url, $model)   {
                        return Html::a('<button class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>',$url, [
                            'class' => 'showModalButton',
                            'id' => 'lead-view',
                            'title' => 'View Customer Details',
                            'value' => $url,
                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                            'data-target' => 'modal',
                          ]);
                    },
                 'update' => function($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>',$url, [
                                'title' => 'Edit Customer Details',
                            ]);
                    },
                'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                      if ($action == 'view') {
                          return Html::a('Action', $url);
                      }
                      if ($action == 'update') {
                         return Html::a('Action', $url);
                      }
                    } 
                ],            
            ],  // fin ActionColumn
        ],
    ]);
} else {
    \yiister\adminlte\widgets\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        "condensed" => false,
        "hover" => true,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'name',
            'mobile_number',
            'sex',
            [ 
                // the attribute 
                'attribute' => 'date', 
                // format the value 
                'value' => function ($model) { 
                    if (extension_loaded('intl')) { 
                        return Yii::t('app', '{0, date, MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm}', [$model->date]); 
                    } else { 
                        return date($model->date); 
                    } 
                }, 
                // some styling? 
                'headerOptions' => [ 
                    'class' => 'col-md-2' 
                ], 
                // here we render the widget 
                'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([ 
                    'model' => $searchModel, 
                    'attribute' => 'date_range',
                    'pluginOptions' => [ 
                        'format' => 'd-m-Y', 
                        'autoUpdateInput' => false 
                    ] 
                ]) 
            ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'officer',
            'value' => 'officer.first_name'
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide filters use short syntax if condition:

```
'filterModel' => $myCondition ? $searchModel : null,
```

To hide `ActionColumn` use `visible` attribute:

```
[
   'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
   'visible' => $myCondition ? true : false,
   // here rest of your code
],
```

Comment: Thank you Yupik. You just saved me a lot my friend. This works fine for me.